# Django: How to apply filter on geometry type using GeoDjango QuerySet

Tags: django, django-queryset, geodjango

I am trying to convert a SQL into Django Query:

```
SELECT * from tbl_name where geometrytype(geometry) LIKE 'POINT';
```

I have searched on it but cannot find any geometry type function, does one exist?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and shortest way (AFAIK) to achieve filtering via geometry type is annotating the query by defining an model Func object, then filtering respectively.

```
from django.db.models import Func

class GeometryType(Func):
    function = "GeometryType"
    output_field = CharField()

#geom is the model's field name for geometry
filtered_qs = ModelName.objects.annotate(geom_type=GeometryType("geom"))
             .filter(geom_type__in={"POINT", "MULTIPOINT"},)
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that stumbles onto this thread, I just created a ticket on the Django issue tracker to implement filtering on `geom_type`: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28696

Answer (score 1):

According to this answer [google djangouser forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/hhFudEnC4Ak)

> "You can't, at least not with current Django versions. Geodjango
>   assumes  that geometry column contains just one type of a geometries.
>
> But you should be able to use .raw() query to get what you want to. "

So i have created this query and it works for me

```
queryset = ModelName.objects.extra(where=["geometrytype(geometry) LIKE 'POINT'"])
```

I am using **extra function** because I have to add some other filters like

```
queryset = ModelName.objects.extra(where=["geometrytype(geometry) LIKE 'POINT'"]).filter(verified__isnull=True, btype__contains='PHONE')
```

**Updated**

GeometryType is a postgis function accroding [GeometryType](http://postgis.net/docs/GeometryType.html)

> GeometryType — Returns the type of the geometry as a string. Eg:
>   'LINESTRING', 'POLYGON', 'MULTIPOINT', etc.

I want to get all those records where geometry type is a POINT.Howevver Django doesn't provide custom filter for **GeometryField**. So I put postgis function **GeometryType** in django query.

Comment: geometrytype() is a custom function? Could you post it, that would help understand what you achieved. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can register a `Lookup` to implement this function, for example:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import GeometryField
from django.db.models import Lookup


class GeometryTypeLookup(Lookup):  # type:ignore
    """
    Geometry type as a lookup
    """

    lookup_name = "type"
    prepare_rhs = False

    def as_sql(self, compiler: Any, connection: Any) -> Any:
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params

        return "GeometryType(%s) ILIKE %s" % (lhs, rhs), params


GeometryField.register_lookup(GeometryTypeLookup)
```

Which you then use like this:

```
queryset = Feature.objects.filter(geom__type="polygon")
```